# GLSL compiles but won't link

Tags: opengl, glsl

EDIT:

NVM ... I found the error after a line by line scan of this 2000 line shader. This should have broke during compile yet it passed ... why? It is literally a line that's like this:

```
uv2.xy -= (someVec3Var.x * someFloatScale) + (anotherVec3Var2* anotherFloatScal);
```

So basically the error is that the first one would generate a float and it is added to a vec3 and it's assigned to a vec2 .... This code works in HSLSL :(

I'm seeing something really weird ... my GLSL compiles but when it links, it complaints for my fragment shader:

```
0(1805) : error C7011: implicit cast from "vec3" to "vec2"
0(1805) : error C7011: implicit cast from "vec4" to "vec3"
0(1808) : error C7011: implicit cast from "vec3" to "vec2"
0(1808) : error C7011: implicit cast from "vec4" to "vec3"
```

I used to have those errors during compile time and I fixed all of them such that it's all good ... but why would they show up in link ? These also happen on different lines than the compile error that was happening prior to my fix. Any reason this would only happen during link time? Could this be due to the fact that I have uniforms name the same across vertex and fragment? I read something in OpenGL ES, they would map to the same memory ... which is fine with me because I want them to be the same variable ... (else why would I name them the same?).

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: It's a 2000 line shader ... lol should I really put it here?

Comment: No, "lol". You should instead make a [MCVE] of the problem. Reduce it to the minimum amount of code that reproduces those errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many GLSL implementations don't actually compile the shaders until you call LinkProgram.  When you call CompileShader it just does a basic syntax sanity check.  That's because to get reasonable performance on most GPUs, whole program optimization is needed.  Thus, you might see what one would normally consider "compile" errors only when you link.